# Can I install the Chrome Browser on the Windows Phone?

Tags: browser

It looks like the answer is No, but I thought I'd check.
(My understanding is that the Windows Phone, like Windows RT, does not allow you to install other browsers).

Comment: Google should think about it.

Comment: In iOS you can't create a new browser too. The Chrome version they have just is a chrome (pun intended) around the browser view control iOS have. It render entirely in the same engine as Safari. But sure they added some functionalities.

Answer (score 11):

No, you cannot. Chrome has not been ported to Windows Phone in fact it hasn't  been ported to iOS either. Google Chrome on iOS is not nothing but Safari with a  different theme and some extra features (Chrome history/tab sync).
Google Chrome so far has been **really** ported to only one mobile platform,  Android.

Note that, porting Chrome to both iOS and Windows Phone is *technically* possible.  This is a legal problem rather than a technical problem. Apple simply won't publish any apps that downloads and runs
executable code.
(Citation: iOS Developer Program License Agreement, 3.3.2)

Microsoft also prohibits usage of some APIs but I honestly don't know if these APIs are
necessary for developing a web browser. I also have taken a quick look at Windows 
Phone
Store Application Provider Agreement but it doesn't seem to have a similar clause to Apple.

Also Chrome **might** actually be available on Windows Phone in future as support  for Windows Phone is according to [this link](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=153802) currently under investigation.

If all you want is Chrome synchronization on Windows Phone you may use [Chrync](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/chrync/cf88cf1c-db73-4db4-8612-758f23c31067).

Comment: An additional factoid that might interest readers: Mozilla was working on a version of Chrome for the recent WinRT API, but apparently gave it up out of disinterest. (I think they, too, would have been severely restricted in terms of scripting engine capabilities)

Comment: The ticket has now been changed to WontFix. (Surprise, surprise...)

Answer (score 4):

Well, there is no such a restriction with browsers on Windows Phone. [UC Browser](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/uc-browser/6cda5651-56b9-48b0-8771-91dbc188f873) is quite nice choice for example. But since there is no Chrome on Windows Store, the answer is no. Unless you want to search for some custom app which is available somewhere in the web, but you're going to need developer unlocked phone for that.

Comment: Actually you can't access low level API to create a new browser . What UC Browser does is using the same IE engine to render the page but making a pre processing in a server to make the page more readable and not so heavy. Opera mobile does this for a long time too.

Comment: @VitorCanova, do you have a citation to verify this?
(I suspect you are right and if so, this answer needs a down vote, which I dont' want to do without proper "evidence"

Comment: @ClayNichols Sorry, couldn't find one. Lets wait for some WP devs.

Answer (score 2):

As per the latest [news](http://www.omgchrome.com/google-chrome-windows-phone-8-1/) Google Chrome could soon be available to install on Windows Phone smartphones. Google chrome may be available for Windows Phone 8.1 or 8.2(9).

[image]

Hope for the best.

Comment: This isn't really "latest" news, and is already covered in [mcsofake's answer](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/3419).

Comment: @Indrek Actually besides both answers point to the same Chromium ticket the `Kiran RS` point out that the ticket was changed to `for investigation`. So I think it is useful.